# Convert string array element to JS object

Tags: javascript, string, mongodb, object, typeof

I'm trying to convert string to object with the below code:

```
wishlisted= [ '626601b89f1c16d0e42fd58e' ]
console.log(wishlisted.map(id => ({ id })));
```

Output for this came as:

```
[ { id: '626601b89f1c16d0e42fd58e' } ]
```

But from the output, I think `id` is of `String` type. I want to return it just like MongoDB's id, like: `626601b89f1c16d0e42fd58e`, not as a string.

When I tried to check the type of `id` using:

```
console.log(typeof wishlisted[0].id);
```

it came as `undefined`.
What could be the best way to do this type casting?

Comment: its undefined because you didn't store the value you just `console.log` it. You need to do `const x = wishlisted.map(id => ({ id }))`  then try `console.log(typeof x[0].id)`